# Does SharePoint 2013 workflow need user profile sychronization service to be running?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-workflow

Does SharePoint 2013 workflow need user profile sychronization  service to be running

Comment: Could you please give more details on the type of solutions you are designed or looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. As long as you have the User Profiles of the setup account, you should be okay with running any workflow in the 2013 workflow engine. The sync service doesn't need to be running, but as long as the sync has run at least once--you should be fine.